# Extracting data from a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array coming from the database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thing1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thing2
        )

)
```

I need to extract the data like this: Thing1, Thing2

I tried a lot of methods, but no one works. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome Devmiki! It's good you show what you are tried, surely you are almost got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['Thing1'],
    ['Thing2']
];

print_r(array_column($data, 0));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Thing1
    [1] => Thing2
)
```

> I need to extract the data like this: `Thing1, Thing2`

```
<?php
echo implode(', ', array_column($data, 0));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the last part was like gold for me!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you want is always in the `0` index of the nested array, you could iterate over the array and extract those elements:

```php
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $result[] = $value[0];
}
```